# Calling C++/CLI DLL from IronPython leading to an "not a valid Win32 application. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800700C1)" error

Tags: c++, c++-cli, wrapper, ironpython

I've been trying to implement this tutorial:
https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/development/dotnet-development/creating-ccli-wrapper/

and even though it works. When I try to call the Wrapper.dll from IronPython I get an error.
I cannot even load the DLL.

This is the IronPython code:

```
import clr

clr.AddReferenceToFileAndPath("Wrapper.dll")
clr.AddReference("mscorlib")

import CLI
import System

if __name__ == "__main__":
    e = CLI.Entity("the guy", 54, -123)
    e.Move(-54, 123)
    System.Console.WriteLine(e.XPosition + " " + e.YPosition)
```

Could anyone please explain what the issue is and hint me a potential solution?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer to my question is:
re-build all projects in x64 just because IronPython used is x64 build.